Is there a better way to replace all non-ASCII characters from specific columns on a DataFrame?
There are some sentences and words in Chinese and Japanese that I just want to drop.
Or if there is a better solution than just dropping them, I would like to explore them as well.
import pandas as pd
import re

# Define the function to check for English text
def is_english(text):
    # Regex pattern for English letters, numbers, and common English symbols
    pattern = r"^[A-Za-z0-9\s.,!?\'\"()@#$%^&*;:\[\]{}±_+=/\\|`~]*$"
    return bool(re.match(pattern, text))


# Apply the function to check each relevant column and create a boolean mask
df["is_english"] = df_clean.apply(
    lambda row: is_english(str(row.get("column_name1", "")))
    if isinstance(row.get("column_name1", ""), str)
    else False and is_english(str(row.get("column_name2", "")))
    if isinstance(row.get("column_name2", ""), str)
    else False,
    axis=1,
)

# Delete rows where at least one relevant column contains non-English characters
df_cleaned = df_clean[listings_clean["is_english"]].drop(
    columns="is_english"
)


Note: good English uses more then just ASCII characters. ASCII set was limited for technical reasons

In any case, your question is ... difficult to answer. You can do what you want. In the question there is no indication on how you will uses the data, which it is important to be able to answer. To much text, we prefer to uses compatible normalization form (but in any language). To detect languages, you need to split in words and check if you encounter the most frequent words in a language (else you are almost testing reduced set or Latin script).

This is just for a personal data cleaning and visualization project. I just want to learn more methods for cleaning the data that I gathered especially with data that is not English.
The data columns are 'comments' and 'names'. This is a fairly large data set and most of them are in English so, I figured, removing some of the rows which are not in English would not hurt.

I would just keep other characters, which may be also used in English names. Else: I would not define it as data cleaning. In data cleaning I would change two (or more) spaces into one, normalize caps (you may get names only in lower case, or only in upper case), etc. And comment: it depends on what you will do. Extracting words may be sensible, but maybe as a separate step, if there are one or more ! (etc.: which may also give sentiment). It depends on what you will do.

And again a rant of 'non-English: The editor house of Ars Technica (and Vogue) is an American house founded more then 100 years ago (circa). And it has still now an accent. Probably the family of the founder still use the accent (American people). Latin American may have similar issues. ASCII was just a subset for computers, not for people (and original ASCII had support for composite characters!)

If you just want to keep ASCII characters, be explicit, select those and drop the rest with str.replace:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['Aaäáαあ今']})
df['ascii'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'[^\x00-\x7F]', '', regex=True)

You can also remove specific character ranges:
# removing CJK, CJK symbols, hiragana, katakana
# you can add all desired blocks here
df['non_chinese_japanese'] = df['col'].str.replace(
    r'[\u4E00-\u9FFF\u3000-\u303F\u3040-\u309F\u30A0-\u30FF]', '', regex=True
)

Output:
          col ascii non_chinese_japanese
0  Aaäáαあ今    Aa              Aaäáα


so "[^\x00-\x7F]" is the regex that will look for all the non-ASCII characters and then replace them with a blank space right? Also this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block is interesting... thanks for this resource... I don't know what keywords to search for this lol.

@MrJxtr '' is the empty string, so this will delete the non-ASCII. You could actually use r'[^\x00-\x7F]+' to delete several successive matches at once, which might be more efficient.

Yes and no, since [^\x00-\x7F] only matches locale-valid characters outside of ASCII, but it doesn't properly capture ill-formed UTF-8 sequences, e.g. an extra trailing \200-\277 byte.

UPDATE
I did some experiments and I found out that I can somewhat achieve the result that I want using this:
I will need to doublecheck the data maybe in the data wrangler to see if everything is as it should be.
Thanks to everyone who posted answers and suggestions.
df["col1"] = df["col1"].apply(
    lambda x: " " if any(ord(char) > 127 for char in x) else x
)
df["col2"] = df["col2"].apply(
    lambda x: " " if any(ord(char) > 127 for char in x) else x
)

